# Play CRUD how to list and show entity as read only outside admin area

Tags: playframework, routes, crud

I am using the crud module for the admin area of my application.

My routes.conf is configured as:

```
*       /admin                                       module:crud
```

What I would like to do is give users a way to list some entities and show the details with read only forms without going through the /admin path.

Is this possible with the crud module or do I need to define a new route and implement controllers and templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new controllers for that, and given the way the CRUD module works, it will be very slow and CPU consuming due to all the reflection involved.

You would be better off by creating the read-only screens yourself.